# Back button on UICollectionView

Tags: swift, button, uiviewcontroller, back

I am trying to add a back/ return button to my UICollectionView, I have this code so far to implement the button:

```
import UIKit

class EmojiPopup: UIView,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate
{
    var collocationView : UICollectionView!
    var arrImagesList:NSMutableArray!

    var blur:UIBlurEffect = UIBlurEffect()

    override init(frame: CGRect)
    {

        super.init(frame: frame)

        arrImagesList = NSMutableArray()
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2)
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        //header gap
        layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(20,20)
        //collection view item size
        layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(70, 70)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 25
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 25
        collocationView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectMake(50,50,UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.screenWidth - 100,UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.screenHeight - 100), collectionViewLayout: layout)
        self.addSubview(collocationView)

        // Create the blurEffect and apply to view
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.ExtraLight)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView.alpha = 0.7
        blurEffectView.frame = self.bounds
        self.addSubview(blurEffectView)

        collocationView.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.002)
        collocationView.dataSource = self
        collocationView.delegate = self
        collocationView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")

        //hide scrollbar
        self.collocationView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false

        //back button
        let btnBack = UIButton(frame:TCRectMake(x:138 ,y:523,width:45,height:45))
        btnBack.setImage(UIImage(named:"back"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        btnBack.addTarget(self, action:"btnBackClick", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.addSubview(btnBack)

        //back button func
        func btnBackClick()
        {

        }

        let fm = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath!
        let items = try! fm.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(path)

        for item in items
        {
            if item.hasSuffix("png") && item.containsString("@") == false && item.containsString("AppIcon") == false && item.containsString("tick_blue") == false && item.containsString("video_camera") == false
            {
                arrImagesList.addObject(item)
            }
        }
    }
    var completeHandler:((String)->())?
    func showDetails(viewParent:UIView,doneButtonClick:((String)->())?)
    {
        completeHandler = doneButtonClick
        viewParent.addSubview(self)
    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return arrImagesList.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let identifier="ImageCell\(indexPath.section)\(indexPath.row)"
        collectionView.registerClass(ImageViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier)

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageViewCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white:1, alpha:0)
        cell.imgView.image = UIImage(named:arrImagesList[indexPath.row] as! String)
        cell.imgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell.imgView.opaque = false
        cell.imgView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

        //keeps blur to background
        self.bringSubviewToFront(collocationView)

        return cell
    }  
//    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
//        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
//        sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
//    {
//        let width=UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width-50
//        return CGSize(width:width/3, height:width/3)
//    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        //let cell=collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ImageViewCell

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations:{
            self.collocationView.alpha=0
            }, completion: { finished in

                if self.completeHandler != nil
                {
                    self.completeHandler!(self.arrImagesList[indexPath.row] as! String)
                }
                self.removeFromSuperview()
        })

    }
    func showDetails(viewParent:UIView,dictData : [String:String],index:Int,doneButtonClick:(()->())?,cancelBUttonClick:(()->())?)
    {
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I want the collection view to be closed if the user presses the back button, but I am not sure what to enter in the back button function. I want the user to be returned back to the main view controller (mapview) if possible

Answer (score 2):

I will assume you are talking about a `UICollectionViewController` and not about a `UICollectionView`. A `UICollectionViewController` has a `UICollectionView` inside. You can "close" (dismiss) a `UICollectionViewController` but not a `UICollectionView`. You can even dismiss a `UIViewController` that has a `UICollectionView` inside.

You have two options:

1. Put you collection view controller (and the main view controller) inside a navigation controller so you can use the default back button already implemented by the navigation controller.
2. You can present the collection view controller modally from the main view controller. Then you need to add a close button (Not back button) that dismiss the controller (The main view controller will stay "behind" so when you dismiss the `UICollectionViewController` it will become visible again.

It's a long way. I suggest you read this [getting started guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson8.html) from Apple, there you can figure it out how navigation controllers and what they do. This is something you need to learn when developing with Swift. I suggest you go further and read the whole tutorial. After reading that chapter you should understand the navigation flow of an iOS application and implement the back-button navigation.

If you find any trouble following that tutorial, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) I am quite new to swift so it isnt so easy to understand. I have updated my question with the full class code. I think I am using a UIVollectionView, have you got any suggestions to achieve back button functionality?

Comment: Yes, you can use any of the two options I gave you. I believe both are the same complexity so it depends what suits you better. You can look for a tutorial of navigation controllers to begin.

Comment: Can you possibly give me an example of what you mean? I am finding it difficult to understand how to implement your suggestion

Comment: Oscar if this worked for you, you should accept this as the correct answer. @Vladimir This helped me. Thank you.

Comment: updated link https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/